# Android Manage External Storage permission

Tags: android, excel, android-manifest, readfile, android-11

We have a feature in our application in which the excel file is to be read & processed.

```
byte[] arr = File.readAllBytes(path);
```

We have tried the solutions System File Picker, Storage Access Framework  and  Media Store API.
However the above solutions only provides the access to metadata of the file.

In our app we read and process the excel file and convert it to base64 for further processing. This can only be achieved with complete file access (`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) for Android 11 & above. We get access denied without this permission.

Play store has rejected the submission as the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` cannot be used anymore.

Comment: `However the above solutions only provides the access to metadata of the file.` Not at all. You can read the whole file. The whole content. No difference. Not a single permission needed if you use SAF.